# delphi d2009 update 3 dcc32 build options. Win XP

Tags: delphi

I have a seemingly unsolvable (to me!) problem.
If I start a simple vcl forms app and try to compile, I get multiple **warning/errors** as follows :

> `[DCC Warning] SysUtils.pas(6082): W1000 Symbol 'SInvalidInteger' is deprecated: 'Use SysConsts.SInvalidInteger'`
>   etc.
>
> `[DCC Fatal Error] Variants.pas(1071): F2092 Program or unit 'Variants' recursively uses itself`

The library path options both in the global and project sections seem Ok,
but if I hover over the dcc32.exe build or output messages, I can see a vast selection of 
paths which are not relevant and also are repeated about 3 times.
The dcc32.cfg is quite short and seems Ok.

It looks like the path is corrupt somehow and although I've reinstalled D2009 (after deleting the program) and also cleared the registry, I cannot seem to solve this problem.

**question :** how can I reset or clear this dcc32.exe path - where is the option file, or is it created on the fly?

This problem occurred when I tried to compile a D7 project/or added JCL/jvcl (now removed)

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: Clear the search path in the options dialog

Comment: Thanks - that worked!!!!! I looked at the path on two different machines visually and they were the same, but one worked OK and yhe other did not - obviously a non-visible character in the string.